# 'Countdown' Numbers round - combine numbers arithmetically to reach a target

Tags: f#, combinatorics, closure

Countdown is a British gameshow where contestants compete in word and number challenges. During the [numbers round](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)#Numbers_round), six numbers are chosen semi-randomly and the task is to combine them using addition, subtraction, multiplication and division in order to reach a target number.

For example, the numbers might be `[75; 25; 7; 2; 5; 8]` and the target `491`.

One winning solution is `((75 + 25) * 5) - 7 - 2 = 491`

Below is some F# code that I wrote to try and improve my functional skills. The `compute` function accepts an `int list` and an `int` and returns an `Expr` which is the closest it could find to the target.

---

First, declaring the recursive type and functions to evaluate and print them

```
module Numbers

type Expr =
| Number of int
| Add of Expr * Expr
| Subtract of Expr * Expr
| Multiply of Expr * Expr
| Divide of Expr * Expr

let rec eval = function
| Number x        -> x     
| Add (x, y)      -> eval x + eval y
| Subtract (x, y) -> eval x - eval y
| Multiply (x, y) -> eval x * eval y
| Divide (x, y)   -> eval x / eval y

// string representation of an expression, with evaluated result
let write n =
    let rec write' = function
    | Number x        -> x.ToString()
    | Add (x, y)      -> "(" + write' x + " + " + write' y + ")"
    | Subtract (x, y) -> "(" + write' x + " - " + write' y + ")"
    | Multiply (x, y) -> "(" + write' x + " * " + write' y + ")"
    | Divide (x, y)   -> "(" + write' x + " / " + write' y + ")"
    write' n + " = " + (eval n).ToString()
```

---

This function that takes an `Expr list` (in the first case, a list of `Number`s) and produces a `seq<Expr list>` which is calculated by all the possible applications of a single arithmetic operator (`+*/-`) to any/all pairs of expressions.

```
let generate exprs =
    // a specialised choose2 function that returns the pair plus the remainders
    // uses indices for comparison in case of duplicate values
    let pairTwo exprs =
        let indexed = List.mapi (fun i x -> i,x) exprs
        [ for (i,x) in indexed do
          for (j,y) in indexed do
          if j > i then
            yield (x,y), [ for (k,z) in indexed do if k <> i && k <> j then yield z ] ]

    // for two given expressions, get possible combinations
    let getExpressions x y =
        let isDivisible x y =
            let denom = eval y
            denom <> 0 && eval x % denom = 0

        let a = max x y
        let b = min x y
        seq {
            yield Multiply (x, y)
            yield Add (x, y)
            yield Subtract(a, b) // don't bother with negatives
            if isDivisible a b
                then yield Divide(a, b)
            yield x // yielding each partial result prevents near-misses getting lost
            yield y // although expands the search tree
        }

    seq {
        for (x,y),zs in pairTwo exprs do
        for expr in getExpressions x y do
        yield expr :: zs }
```

---

Finally the compute function which drives the calculation, iterating over all candidate expressions until a match is found or there are no more possibilities

```
let compute numbers target =
    let distance = eval >> ((-) target) >> abs
    let fitness = Seq.map distance >> Seq.min

    let iterate =
        Seq.collect generate
        >> Seq.sortBy fitness

    let rec compute' candidates =
        let first = Seq.head candidates
        match first, fitness first with
        | x::[], _  -> x // no more iterations, this is the best one
        | exprs,  0 -> Seq.minBy distance exprs // woop, got it
        | _,     _  -> candidates |> iterate |> compute'
    seq { yield numbers |> List.map Number }
    |> compute'
```

---

I'd really like feedback on my use of closures, pattern matching, choices of list vs seq, and if anyone can think of a nicer way to implement the `pairTwo` function I would like to see it

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly simplified the `generate` function by merging the `pairTwo` function into the resulting `seq` computation expression. I refrained from merging the `getExpressions` function, as its functionality is distinct enough to warrant a separate function IMO.

```
let generate exprs =
    // for two given expressions, get possible combinations
    let getExpressions x y =
        let isDivisible x y =
            let denom = eval y
            denom <> 0 && eval x % denom = 0

        let a,b = if x > y then x,y else y,x
        seq {
            yield Multiply (x, y)
            yield Add (x, y)
            yield Subtract(a, b) // don't bother with negatives
            if isDivisible a b
                then yield Divide(a, b)
            yield x // yielding each partial result prevents near-misses getting lost
            yield y // although expands the search tree
        }

    let indexed = List.mapi (fun i x -> i,x) exprs

    seq {
        for (i,x) in indexed do
        for (j,y) in indexed do
        if j > i then
            for expr in getExpressions x y do
            yield expr :: [ for (k,z) in indexed do if k <> i && k <> j then yield z ] }
```

I would still very much appreciate any and all critique!

Answer (score 1):

I find the logic a bit hard to follow, especially in `compute'`, so I'll just comment on some minor issues and post some recommended reading.

> ```
> | x::[], _  -> x
> ```

Is more commonly written

```
| [x], _ -> x
```

Using point-free style here is distracting:

> ```
> let distance = eval >> ((-) target) >> abs
> ```

I find this much clearer:

```
let distance expr = abs (target - eval expr)
```

This does not do what you want:

> ```
> let a = max x y
> let b = min x y
> ```

For example,

```
> max (Number 100) (Add (Number 1, Number 2)) ;;

val it : Expr = Add (Number 1,Number 2)
```

You want something like this instead

```
let a, b = if eval x >= eval y then x, y else y, x
```

Graham Hutton wrote a paper on solving this problem in Haskell, which is a great read. You can find it [here](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/countdown.pdf). It would be a good exercise to port the solution to F#.

> We systematically develop a functional program that solves the
>   countdown problem, a numbers game in which the aim is to construct
>   arithmetic expressions satisfying certain constraints. Starting from a
>   formal specification of the problem, we present a simple but
>   inefficient program that solves the problem, and prove that this
>   program is correct. We then use program fusion to calculate an
>   equivalent but more efficient program, which is then further improved
>   by exploiting arithmetic properties.

Comment: Thank you. I had realised the min/max issue since posting and implemented the same fix that you gave which is reassuring. Now that you mention it, the point-free style is a bit OTT for the distance function so I have reimplemented per your suggestion. About the complexity of the compute function, I agree it is a little hard to follow. I'll check out the Haskell paper (been a while since I did any of that) and see if I can relate the logic back to my program. Cheers for the link